# Execute 2 functions in the same event

Tags: javascript, events

It´s possible execute 2 functions in the same event ? , for example this :

**Inside input field :**

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="ok" onclick="function1();function2();">
```

As you can see inside the event onclick i put 2 functions for execute when the people over the field and do click , it´s possible do this and works finally or exists other way for do this ?

Thank´s for the helps , the best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick="function3();"
```

**js**

```
function function3 (){
    function1();
    function2();
 }
```

Comment: Thank´s i go to try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the second function `function2()` in the first function `function1()`.

```
function function1() {
    function2();
    // Do other things
}
```

And call the first function `function1()` on `click`

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="ok" onclick="function1();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Call one main function which calls both others.

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="ok" onclick="function3();">

function3(){
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you are doing is correct

```
onclick="function1();function2();"
```

It works fine.

And other way is  callling `function2` in the end of first function.

```
function function1() {

    //function 1 stuff

 function2();
}
```